# When and how to use “hasta luego”?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context

One of my colleagues used this as their subject in the mail while leaving the office. Is there any other place it can be used, and is this wise to use this in general speech?

Comment: This is "English" language and usage. That is a *Spanish* phrase. It means "see you later". Use it when you are very informally saying goodbye to someone you will see again, who won't say, "Huh?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using a Spanish phrase, and is POB to boot.

Comment: So in @medica's opinion it should be given the boot.

Comment: Rather than closing this question, I'd propose it be migrated to [ell.se]. English speakers borrow stock phrases from Spanish or French rather often; this would be a good question over at ELL.

Comment: @medica This is an English question, not a Spanish question. Moreover, we sometimes use the construction in English differently than the Spanish do.

Comment: @J.R. I’ve tried to make the answer a bit more ELU-ish than ELL-ish, but I wouldn’t be completely surprised if it popped up there, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an English question, not a Spanish question.  Most people who use this phrase in English do not in fact know any Spanish at all, just as those who use *Bon voyage!* or *Bon appétit!* may well know no French to speak of.

English speakers, particularly in America, not uncommonly use the phrase *hasta luego* borrowed from Spanish in their English-language speech as a way of saying *See ya!*

The Spanish preposition *hasta* corresponds to English *until, till*. There are lots of versions of these various *hasta **X*** phrases floating around, the most common probably being ones like these:

- *Hasta la vista*
  Close to French *au revoir*, so in Spanish essentially (not literally) “till we see each other again” but not quite so formally; more like “see ya later” or “be seein’ ya”  perhaps.
- *Hasta luego*
  Literally “till then” in the original Spanish.
- *Hasta mañana*
  Literally “till tomorrow” in the original Spanish.
- *Hasta la mañana*
  Literally “till morning” in the original Spanish.
- *Hasta después*
  Literally “till later” or perhaps “till afterwards” in the original Spanish.

Your phrase, *hasta luego*, is a very general thing which is heard all the time here in the southwest United States. It just means “until whenever”; it is not as long-term as *hasta la vista*.

All are rather casual, and you should not expect listeners to use them per their exact original senses from Spanish. This frequently occurs with loanwords or phrases; they warp in meaning compared with the original version.

This *hasta **X*** construction has been further naturalized into English by people using a target *X* that is not even Spanish.  Perhaps influenced by the famous movie phrase “Hasta la vista, baby” from *Terminator II*, people also sometimes say:

- *Hasta la bye-bye*

Which makes no sense at all, but they say it anyway.  So you could even consider *hasta **X*** as moderately productive in English. If you’re into rhymes, then

- *Hasta la pasta*

also works.  In English it would probably mean “till supper” with *pasta* having the English sense and so here used as a tongue-in-cheek metanym — although in Spanish it could carry other meanings because *pasta* has more meanings there than it does in English, including slang for *money*.

In fact, *hasta* has become so  common in English here that people say simply *Hasta* as a general sign-off without specifying until when:

- *Hasta!*

I have never heard it used that way in Spanish, only in English.

I cannot tell you whether it is appropriate in casual speech in your own social circles. But clearly your colleague is comfortable with it, even in writing, so that perhaps tells you something.

Note that the English pronunciations are also somewhat naturalized into English from the original versions, since both of the two most common ones (*hasta la vista, hasta luego*) contain sounds in Spanish that do not even occur in English.

Comment: Excellent answer, tchrist.

Comment: Although these are phrases used in English, might it not be useful to say what the Spanish actually means?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I was avoiding making it seem like a Spanish question, but very well: *Hasta la vista* means *Au revoir*. :)

Comment: Hasta lasagna...

Comment: It might also be relevant, when talking about the difference between the Spanish and the English pronunciation, to note that in English, _hasta luego_ is more or less pronounced as you’d expect, something like [ˈ(h)ɑːstə luˈeɪɡoʊ] (with or without the initial h), whereas in Spanish, the most common pronunciation in normal speech seems to be [taˈlu̯ε͡o] (sort of like _’ta lue’o_), with only two syllables.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That can end up a phonetic triphthong though the ES phonemic trips don’t normally include /wew/. At least 4 distinct phenomena at work here: ⓵Weak approximates [β̞], [ð̞], [ɣ̞] are subject to lenition (*hablado>hablao*) ⓶Fusion of paired vowels across hiatal (syllabic) boundaries into diphthong (*poeta, maestro*). ⓷Closing of final [o̞] into [u̯] (*hablau*). ⓸Incomplete historical diphthongization of *ɔ>we, ɛ>je*  (*logo, fogo, tenes*). So Madrid’s version of “Gotta light?” written *¿Tienes fuego?* can **sound** very like Lisbon’s *Tens fogo?* — and good luck getting [ɣ̞]. 

Comment: @tchrist And ⓹ Deletion of unstressed _has-_. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yeah but I maxed out my char count. :) That one may owe something to the Andalusian and Caribbean tendency to aspirate syllable-final *s* (and open previous vowel). That whole leading syllable gets lost easily enough: just compare Latin *stare* becoming ES, PT *estar* but [Asturian *tar*](http://ast.wiktionary.org/wiki/tar) with no leading *es-* at all any longer.